# Parse issue after importing AFNetworking and UIKIT+AFNetworking

Tags: afnetworking-2

I am getting getting 8 parse issues in Xcode after importing AFNetworking and UIKIT+AFNetworking from the master release. I haven't done anything yet, just used `#import AFNetworking.h` and received following errors on this line in `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h`

```
@property (readonly, nonatomic, strong) NSURL *baseURL;
```

The errors are:

```
/workspace/MD/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h:90:48: Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
/workspace/MD/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h:90:1: Property requires fields to be named

/workspace/MD/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h:90:48: Expected ';' at end of declaration list

/workspace/MD/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h:90:48: Expected an Objective-C directive after '@'
```

I'm also receiving the same errors in `AFHTTPSessionManager.h`. I am not using any of the classes yet, and am still getting these errors. Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had a same name constant which was causing the error